# Replace conditional with polimorphism how to

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I would like to replace the if statements in the following recursive function with polimorphism.

i read alot about it, see several youtube videos but still, cannot see the way of actually doing it on my code (that was simplified for the purpose of this post)

what makes this task more difficult for me is the presence of a foreach statment at the begining of the function and the recursive call

thanks for the help

```
public void FlattenXml(XElement xml, string id = null)
{
    var elements = xml.Elements().ToList();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        if (element.Name == "name1")
        {
            Func1();
        }
        if (element.Name == "name2")
        {
            Func2();
        }
        if (element.Name == "name3")
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
            FlattenXml(content, tempId);
            Func3();
        }
        else
        {
            DoSomethingCompletelyDifferent();
            FlattenXml(element, id);
        }
    }
    xml.Elements("name3").Remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by replace "with polimorphism"?

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: This refactoring does not really fit here. You _can_ create a bunch of classes if you really want to, but it will not improve the code in this particular case.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? It seems like the completely wrong thing to do in this example.

Comment: If there are a ton of things happening in each of the `if()` case and you imagine yourself adding more cases that could contain duplicate code, then I'd probably go for the `Strategy` pattern... but as it stands, I won't refactor it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use design pattern with the beauty of code then I will suggest you to use Polymorphism, strategy pattern, and pattern search.

It will give the advantage of code enhancement and reusability.

Below code example:

```
public interface ISomeOperation
{
    string DoOperation(string data);
}

public class OperationA : ISomeOperation
{
    public string DoOperation(string data)
    {
        //implemention.  
        return data;
    }
}

public class OperationB : ISomeOperation
{
    public string DoOperation(string data)
    {
        //implemention. 
        return data;
    }
}

public class OperationC : ISomeOperation
{
    public string DoOperation(string data)
    {
        //implemention.  
        return data;
    }
}

public class OperationD : ISomeOperation
{
    public string DoOperation(string data)
    {
        //implemention.  
        return data;
    }
}

public class OperationContext
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ISomeOperation> _operationStrategy = new Dictionary<string, ISomeOperation>();

    public OperationContext()
    {
        _operationStrategy.Add("name1", new OperationA());
        _operationStrategy.Add("name2", new OperationB());
        _operationStrategy.Add("name3", new OperationC());
        _operationStrategy.Add("name4", new OperationD());
    }

    public string GetOperationData(string searchType, string data)
    {
        return _operationStrategy[searchType].DoOperation(data);
    }
}
```

//Driver Code:

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var operationContext = new OperationContext();
        var elements = xml.Elements().ToList();
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            operationContext.GetOperationData(element.Name, element);
        }
    }
}
```

Node: Multiple methods should be called in one method.

Comment: the only thing about this pattern is that the OperationContext constractor keeps growing as new names get added, but is  pretty close to what I want to do

Comment: You can move OperationContext constructor's adding into dictionary operation to a method. A d then you can call that method into constructor.

Comment: _how come this is so **easily** comprehensible..?_ elucidation worth thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For this situation, polymorphism is understood through the concept of "types" and "behaviors".  The three "names" indicate three different types - but you also have an "else", so there are four types to work with.

(Question - did you intend the `if`s to be a full if/else chain?  In this code, `else` is executed for "name1" and "name2".  My answer depends on a full if/else chain...)

To make it a little easier to understand, consider this code:

```js
public void FeedAnimals(Menagerie x)
{
    var animals = x.getAnimals()
    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        if (animal.Name == "cat")
        {
            FeedTheCat();
        } else if (animal.Name == "dog")
        {
            feedTheDog();
        } else if (animal.Name == "bees")
        {
            PutOnBeeSuit();
            foreach(bee in bees) FeedAnimals(new Menagerie() {bee});
        }
        else
        {
            CallAMeeting();
            FeedAnimals(new Menagerie() {employees});
        }
    }
}
```

(this is all pseudo-code, btw)

You can now see how each "animal" type is being "fed".  But the act of feeding *could* be different.  This is where polymorphism comes into play - you shift your thinking from making a decision about what should be done with the data to creating a "type" that has "behaviors" you can apply.

In this case, the general "type" is "animal" and the behavior is "feed".  Polymorphism is the part where you differentiate from the general type into specific types:

```js
class Animal {
  public function Feed() {}
}

class Cat inheritsfrom Animal {
  public function Feed() {}
}

class Bee inheritsfrom Animal {
  public function Feed() {}
}

class Dog inheritsfrom Animal {
  public function Feed() {}
}

class BeeHive {
  list of Bee bees
}
```

So now your logic can shift to something like:

```js
public void FeedAnimals(List(of Animal) menagerie, string id = null)
{
    foreach (var animal in menagerie)
    {
        if (animal is Cat)
        {
          animal.Feed();
        } else if (animal is Dog)
        {
            animal.Feed();
        } else if (animal is Bee)
        {
            PutOnBeeSuit();
            animal.Feed();
        } else if (animal is BeeHive) {
          FeedAnimals animal.bees
        } else
        {
            CallAMeeting();
            animal.feed();
        }
    }
}
```

See how you end up calling ".Feed" all the time?  That's a good thing.  Since Cat, Dog, Bee inherit from animal, they actually have a different "Feed" function, and the language knows which one to call, based on what type is being referenced.  And the type is automatically associated with the variable (behind the scenes).

So now, with one minor change to BeeHive, the code collapses to:

```js
// new BeeHive class:
class BeeHive inheritsfrom Animal{
  list of Bee bees
  public function Feed() { 
    foreach(bee in bees) bee.Feed()
  }
}

// new, collapsed code
public void FeedAnimals(List( of Animal) menagerie, string id = null) {
  foreach(var animal in menagerie) {
    if (animal is Animal) {
      CallAMeeting()
    }
    animal.Feed()
  }
}
```

I hope this helps clear up the process of thinking through a polymorphism implementation.

Don't forget, this is ALL pseudo-code, and there ARE errors in the code.  It's here to express concepts, it's not here to run (or even compile).

Comment: you changed the first parameter of "FeedAnimals" from "Menagerie x" to "List( of Animal) menagerie" can you explain to what should I change my "XElement xml" parameter?

Comment: Nope.  I made that change to show the contextual difference between a class and a list.  All of my code was instruction, and should not be taken as  any kind of solution.  It's just there to help you think about moving from data-based thinking to class-based thinking.  I'll edit variable names to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to solve that situation replacing Conditional Logic with Strategy pattern.

Search *"Replace Conditional Logic with Strategy"* a Martin Fowler's book and read ["Refactoring to Patterns: Simplification"](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398607&seqNum=2) by Joshua Kerievsky

uml:
  [image: uml]

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is based on types. You can execute different functions (in your case the statements in the if blocks) based on the type of the object (which has a common base type).

In your case you want to do different things based on a string. So, you either create a type from a string and them use polymorphism or you use a map (in C# called Dictionary) to map from a string to a function (e.g. a lambda expression, or Action in C#). Depending on the complexity of the different functions and the actual meaning of "nameN" choose the one or the other.

The recursion function would be a part of the base object in one case, or would have to be called from the lambda in the other case.